# How to reverse modulo of a multiplication?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, inverse

I am primarily a programmer (rather than a mathematician) and have recently come across a coding problem where I must invert a function which is the the modulo of a multiplication (given certain constraints which ensure that there is a 1 to 1 mapping between the inputs and the outputs of the function), and I cannot seem to work out how to do it.

Given the following:

`(x * a) % b = c`

Where `0 <= x <= b`

and `0 <= a <= b`

and (in case it matters) where the lowest common multiple of `a` and `b` is `a * b` (is co-prime the correct term for this?).

I want to find the inverse function which will give me `x`, when I know `a`, `b`, and `c`. More specifically, if `b` and `c` are kept constant, and `c` is varied, I want to work out what `x` is.

In order to try to work it out myself, I set `a = 3` and `b = 16`. I chose these numbers because the lowest common multiple of 3 and 16 is 3 * 16, which is one of the constraints. I then wrote down a list of all possible values of `x` (between 0 and 15) and the corresponding values for `c`, using the equation `c = (x * 3) % 16`

```
(0 * 3) % 16 =  0    ( 6 * 3) % 16 =   2    (11 * 3) % 16 =   1
(1 * 3) % 16 =  3    ( 7 * 3) % 16 =   5    (12 * 3) % 16 =   4
(2 * 3) % 16 =  6    ( 8 * 3) % 16 =   8    (13 * 3) % 16 =   7
(3 * 3) % 16 =  9    ( 9 * 3) % 16 =  11    (14 * 3) % 16 =  10
(4 * 3) % 16 = 12    (10 * 3) % 16 =  14    (15 * 3) % 16 =  13
(5 * 3) % 16 = 15
```

I have arranged this in columns, such that each time the value of `c` "wraps around", a new column is started. From this, I can derive an equation based on the column number:

`x = (c + ((column_number - 1) * 16)) / 3`

E.g.:

```
x = (12 + (0 * 16)) / 3 = 4
x = ( 2 + (1 * 16)) / 3 = 6
x = (10 + (2 * 16)) / 3 = 14
```

What I cannot see, is how to derive the correct amount to multiply by 16 in order to generalise the equations so that I can use it for any `c` in the above table (i.e. how to derive the "column_number").

Comment: If $a,b$ are coprime, then there are integers $u,v$ such that $au+bv=1$, which gives $au \mod b = 1$, that is, $u$ is the multiplicative inverse of $a$. Then $a (cu) \mod b = c$. In the above, for $a=3$, $b=16$ you have $u=11$, so the formula is $x=(11 c \mod 16)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look up the Euclidean algorithm, which you can write into your code.  Since $a$ and $b$ are coprime, the Euclidean algorithm lets you find $s$ and $t$ such that $$a\cdot s+t\cdot b=1$$ and it does it fairly quickly. This means that $$a\cdot s\equiv1\mod{b}$$ So then you can multiply the sides of your original equation ($x\cdot a\equiv c\mod{b}$) by the $s$ that is output from the Euclidean algorithm, and: 
$$\begin{align}
x\cdot a\cdot s&\equiv c\cdot s\mod{b}\\
x\cdot 1&\equiv c\cdot s\mod{b}\\
x&\equiv c\cdot s\mod{b}
\end{align}$$
and you can reduce $c\cdot s$ down so that you get something in between $0$ and $b$.

There is no significantly quicker algorithm to do this for general $a$, $b$, and $c$ than what is outlined here. That is, there is no closed form formula for $x$ in terms of $a$, $b$ and $c$ that could be programmed to be computed quicker.

Comment: FWIW, it'd have been nice to include a link for your “Look up the Euclidean algorithm” part. The relevant Wikipedia link is [_the Extended Euclidean algorithm_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) (looking up the code for regular `gcd`, which is what people usually think of for Euclid's algorithm, is not so helpful!).  Also useful is Wikipedia's page on [_Modular multiplicative inverse_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse).